# usb scanner has a beam but no beep

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, barcode

I've a c# win 8.1 app, which uses a scanner to enter barcode info. The windows 8 machines are on 24/7. The issue I have is that after a period of a few weeks or so, the scanners emit a beam but the scan is not firing through to the PC/no beep! Rebooting has no effect! I've scanned in the set up barcodes. The temp solution is to remove the USB scanner and plug it back in. An easy fix but a pain when it involves some 40 machines. The PC's are on win 8.1. I'm pretty sure it's nothing to do with my app. would anyone know what the solution to this issue may? Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like it is not decoding the bar code. What is the make and model of the scanner. This type of question is outside of the scope of this site but I will try to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Shane. The scanners are Honeywell 1300g.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem goes away immediately when you unplug it and plug it back in? The reason I ask is that it sounds like a decoding/read issue and that should not be affected by unplug/plug.

Comment: Very sure. Would/should the decode/read go away with a reboot? As the issue persists following the reboot. Could it be the machines?